# How to use PARSE_XML in SnowSQL where the underlying XML is "broken"?

Tags: python, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working with a very large collection of XML files (1m+) and for some reason most of them are "broken"

That is to say, running `CHECK_XML()` on them returns all sorts of errors (missing tag name after <, prematurely terminated xml, etc...)

Is there any way to parse this in snowflake?

I could (as a work-around) use snowpark and pass the python `lxml.html.fromstring` parser (which does work!), but I'd rather not do this to keep my code simple.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can validate it to sort out it before to o.k. / n.o.k. files with [xmlschema](https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/).

Comment: A search for "parse broken XML" gives 738 hits: I hope you will find some of the answers relevant. I chose one of them pretty much at random. The solutions break down into 3 types: (a) get the supplier of the faulty XML to fix their bugs, (b) use a repair tool such as TagSoup, (c) if the breakages are predictable enough, write your own repair utility using non-XML technologies.